# Camera Follow Script destroys Raycast on VR-Hands with Late Update

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, virtual-reality, raycasting

I have a Camera-Follow-Script that follows the player using "Late-Update". It moves my entire VR-Player around, including the VR-Hands on which i have a raycast script with a line-renderer that visualizes the raycast.

The thing is, that the raycast or the linerenderer is flickering up and down. I tried to fix it for a while until I found out that it's actually cause by the late-update in my script that is moving the entire vr-player in which the hands and the raycast are included.

When I change my camera-follow script to "Update" instead of "Late-Update" everything is working fine with the raycast, but the player-follow movement is stuttering.

Here is my Camera-Follow-Script:

```
public Transform player;

public float smoothSpeed = 0.125f;
public Vector3 offset;

private void LateUpdate()
{
    Vector3 desiredPosition = player.position + offset;
    Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(player.position, desiredPosition, smoothSpeed);
    transform.position = smoothedPosition;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a LayerMask and place player on a seperate layer, so your raycast doesn't hit the player's colliders. If you are not using layers already its a great way to speed up your physics processing (i.e. you only raycast against stuff that is important from the point of view of player interaction and physix doesn't have to go through ALL the colliders in the scene to fetch your raycast hit.